# is $e^{-A_t}$ continuous process and why?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

A is a nondecreasing process.
Exponential function is continuous function, but if A has jumps, $e^{-A_t}$ will have jumps as well or it's not true?

Comment: Since $e^x$ is strictly monotonic, it's invertible on it's range so yes, it will jump whenever $A_t$ jumps.

Comment: @AlexR. why then quadratic covariation $[N, e^{-A_t}]=0$ where N is a arbitrary semimartingale